# GitlabCI run pipeline on specific branch using wild card

Tags: gitlab, yaml, pipeline, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to trigger a pipeline everytime the current milestone branch changes it works fine with hardcoded milistone number 
the problem is that we increase the milestone number, every 2 weeks 
and  gitlab runner doesn't parse `.gitlab-ci.yml` wildcards
so things like that not working

```
job:
  only:
    - milestone-*
```

i also tried regex as suggested BY  Makoto Emura here at the comments

```
java:
  only:
    - /^mileston-.*$/
```

for now i use it this way and update my `.gitlab-ci.yml` after creating a new milestone

```
job:
  only:
    - milestone-10
```

I try to look for an environment variable for target branch but didn't find any

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: It seems like you have the option to use regex to specify the "only" condition, as shown in the example of the [`.gitlab-ci.yml` docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified). I've never tried it before though.

Comment: As i mention in the question i try it and it isn’t working

Comment: You didn't mention in the question that you tried regex.

Comment: you right sorry try it also and it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested with this regex and it works :

```
    only:
    - /^milestone-.*$/
```

In your comment, you wrote  `/^mileston-.*$/` instead of `/^milestone-.*$/` (the `e` is missing at the end of milestone)